# Убрать из многомерного массива PHP ключи значение которых равно 0

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Не получается удалить из массива ключи значение которых равно нулю.

```
Array
(
    [dfgfgdfgdsfgdfg] => Array
        (
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 1
            [8] => 0
        )

    [dsfdsfsdfdsffs] => Array
        (
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 1
            [8] => 0
        )

)
```

На выходе должно получиться

```
Array
(
    [dfgfgdfgdsfgdfg] => Array
        (
            [4] => 1
        )

    [dsfdsfsdfdsffs] => Array
        (
            [2] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: тут нет ключей равных нулю. задача решена

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, а разве [2] => 0 2 - это не ключ??

Comment: да, 2 - ключ. Но 2 это не ноль, что логично

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Ну значит Удалить ключи значение которых равно 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное самый простой вариант `(в переменной $data находится ваш массив)`

```
foreach ($data as &$arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $item) {
        if (empty($item)) {
            unset($arr[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
$arr = ваш массив;
$res = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $arr1) {
     $sub_res = array();
     foreach ($arr1 as $k1 => $v1) {
         if ($v1) {
              $sub_res[$k1] = $v1;
         }
     }
     if ($sub_res) {
          $res[$k] = $sub_res;
     }
}

$res - то что вам нужно
```